Add-in Express Hides all ribbon tab button and show 2 buttons only in c#
I have an existing Excel add-in project called "exampleBi" developed using the Add-in Express framework in C#. Within this project, I've implemented a new sign-in form in a Windows Form application. Upon clicking the sign-in button, I want to open an Excel file in a new window. However, in this new window, I only want to display two specific buttons and hide all others programmatically.
Is it possible to achieve this functionality using C# at runtime? If so, what approach or API should I use to selectively hide buttons within the Excel window?
following code is exist in sign-in button click event
            if (signinFlag)
            {
                this.Close();
               
                Application excelApp = new Application();
                excelApp.Visible = true;

                // Open the Excel file in a new window
                var path = @"C:\Ariyanayagan\Excel\People_2_28_2024_6_08_25_PM.xlsx";
                Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);

                //here i want hide Ribbon tab button
            }
          
            // Hide all Ribbon UI
            excelApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro("SHOW.TOOLBAR(\"Ribbon\", false)");

            // Optionally, you can also hide the formula bar
            excelApp.DisplayFormulaBar = false;

        

I use these lines but it entirely hides the Ribbon tab. I want to show Only two buttons.
